# Cipher.getBlockSize() returns 128 bits even with 256 bit key

Tags: java, encryption, key, aes

I am trying to get some AES encryption going. I want to use AES-256.

`aesKey.length = 32` or 256 bits. However, `Cipher.getBlockSize()` is returning `16` or 128 bits. Shouldn't `Cipher.getBlockSize()` return `32` instead of `16` if I am using AES-256? Or am I misunderstanding this method?

I'm just trying to determine if I am using AES-128 or -256.

```
byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];

SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, 0, aesKey.length, "AES");
Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);

System.out.println(enc.getBlockSize() * 8);
```

Comment: Block size & key size is not the same .. AES blocksize is always 128 bit, and key size can be 128, 192 or 256 bit

Comment: Maybe you should first look up how a cipher is defined before using it. ECB mode is almost always insecure. What about using `KEY_SIZE = 256` as constant and then use `KEY_SIZE / Byte.SIZE` as to create your byte array? What about the two argument constructor of `SecretKeySpec`? Note that I've indicated to my previous manager multiple times that people that are very sloppy on details like this should not be touching (my) crypto code, as they *will* make mistakes that will someday result in an exploitable bug.

Answer (score 4):

AES has a block size of 128 bit. This does not depend on the key size you are using.

You cannot change the block size, however you can change the key size. AES is specified to support 128, 192 and 256 bit keys.